# Multiple GET Requests per second using channels

Tags: go, concurrency

I am attempting to write a simple program that sends a given number of concurrent GET requests per second, so let's say I want to send 10 requests at a frequency of 5 per second. In this case it means we want to send 5 concurrent requests twice for a total of 10 requests.

I have implemented this using channels, but I am not sure if this is the right approach:

Edited

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    transactions := 10
    frequency := 5
    prepareRequests(frequency, transactions)

}

func prepareRequests(frequency int, transactions int) {
    transactionsPerSecond := transactions / frequency
    c := make(chan string)
    link := "http://google.com"
    for i := 0; i < transactionsPerSecond; i++ {
        fmt.Println("batch: ", i+1)
        for j := 0; j < frequency; j++ {
            go sendRequests(link, c)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)

    }

    for k :=0; k < frequency; k++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
}

func sendRequests(l string, c chan string) {
    _, err := http.Get(l)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(l, "might be down!")
        c <- l
        return
    }

    c <- l
}
```

Updated
[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/I-qlreym7Eg)

Is this correct? Seems to be working, but I am not sure I am actually sending concurrent GET request through the sub routines.

Comment: This is leaking every request goroutine and connection (which includes other goroutines). You're ignoring the response, which you need in order to consume the body. Nothing is reading from the channels, so all sends block. What do you want to do with the channels?

Comment: @JimB, I see. I edited the code and playground to address your comments. I am simply trying to send 2 GET requests at the same time, wait for 1 second, then send two more at the same time until 10 requests are sent total. Does it make sense?

Comment: You're still not handling the response which may cause problems, but otherwise this should function. It would make sense that if you're not sure if it's working, to actually test it to verify that it works as expected, in which case you'd see that your math doesn't work, you're sending 2 requests every second.

Comment: @JimB, good catch, I updated the code to reflect this, and now the frequency is 5 per second, thanks!